# Manipulating Common Fractions

Tags: java, beginner

I'm a beginner Java student currently learning from *Absolute Java* 5<sup>th</sup> edition. I think I understand the content well but I am never sure of my style. This code is for a question after the second chapter on defining classes. I haven't learned arrays or recursion yet.

- Am I following or close to best coding practices?
- Am I committing any serious style errors?
- Is my decomposition OK?
- Readability?

The textbook question is written in the opening comments.

```
/*
 * Define a class called Fraction. This class is used to represent a ratio of two integers. 
 * Include mutator methods that allow the user to set the numerator and the denominator. 
 * Also include a method that displays the fraction on the screen as a ratio (e.g., 5/9). 
 * This method does not need to reduce the fraction to lowest terms. 
 * 
 * Include an additional method, equals, that takes as input another Fraction and returns 
 * true if the two fractions are identical and false if they are not. This method should 
 * treat the fractions reduced to lowest terms; that is, if one fraction is 20/60 and the
 * other is 1/3, then the method should return true.
 * 
 * Embed your class in a test program that allows the user to create a fraction. Then the 
 * program should loop repeatedly until the user decides to quit. Inside the body of the 
 * loop, the program should allow the user to enter a target fraction into an anonymous 
 * object and learn whether the fractions are identical. 
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionClass {
    int num, den;
    public FractionClass(int startingNum, int startingDen) {
        if (startingDen == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error. Denominator cannot equal zero.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        num = startingNum;
        den = startingDen;
    }

    // Mutator method to set the numerator
    public void setNum(int newNum) {
        num = newNum;
    }

    // Mutator method to set the denominator which cannot equal zero
    public void setDen(int newDen) {
        if (newDen == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error. Denominator cannot equal zero.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        den = newDen;
    }

    // Displays the fraction in standard form as a String
    public String toString() {
        return (num + "/" + den); 
    }

    // Two FractionClass objects are considered equal if the reduced forms of each fraction are equal
    public boolean equals(FractionClass otherObject) {
        reduceFraction();
        otherObject.reduceFraction();
        boolean numEqual = (this.num == otherObject.num);
        boolean denEqual = (this.num == otherObject.num);
        return (numEqual && denEqual);
    }

    // Reduces the fraction using Euclid's Algorithm Method
    // Pre-Condictions: The calling object has a valid numerator and denominator
    // Post-Conditions: The calling object's numerator and denominator are reduced
    private void reduceFraction() {
        int GCD = euclidGCD(num, den);
        num = num / GCD;
        den = den / GCD;
    }

    // Euclid's Algorithm. Takes two integers and returns the greatest common divisor. 
    private int euclidGCD(int a, int b) {
        while (a != 0 && b != 0) {
            int c = b;
            b = a%b;
            a = c;
        }
        return a+b;
    }

    private static final String EXIT_KEYWORD = "exit"; // Keyword to end the main program loop

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numInput, denInput;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        boolean resume = true;        
        boolean fractionsEqual;
        while (resume) {
            numInput = readNum(kb);
            denInput = readDen(kb);
            FractionClass firstFraction = new FractionClass(numInput, denInput);
            System.out.println("You entered the fraction: " + numInput + "/" + denInput);
            System.out.println("Now we will compare that to a new fraction.");
            numInput = readNum(kb);
            denInput = readDen(kb);
            fractionsEqual = firstFraction.equals(new FractionClass(numInput, denInput));
            if (fractionsEqual) {
                System.out.println("The fractions are equal.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The fractions are not equal.");
            }

            resume = shouldResume(kb);
        }
    }

    // Reads an integer numerator and returns the value
    private static int readNum(Scanner kb) {
        System.out.println("Enter a numerator: ");
        return kb.nextInt();
    }

    // Reads a non zero integer denominator and returns the value
    private static int readDen(Scanner kb) {
        boolean incorrectInput = true;
        int denInput = 1;
        while (incorrectInput) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a denominator that doe not equal zero ");
            denInput = kb.nextInt();
            if (denInput != 0) incorrectInput = false;
        }
        return denInput;
    }


    // Asks the user if they want to run the program again
    // Returns false if the user input matches the exit keyword defined as a constant otherwise returns true
    private static boolean shouldResume(Scanner kb) {
        String resumeAnswer = "";
        System.out.println("Please enter \"" + EXIT_KEYWORD + "\" to exit the program or enter any key to run the program again.");
        resumeAnswer = kb.next();
        resumeAnswer = resumeAnswer.toLowerCase();
        if (resumeAnswer.equals(EXIT_KEYWORD)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need both `readNum()` and `readDen()` methods, with the latter performing input validation. What you can consider is to take two integer inputs and pass them into a static factory method that will do the validation for you, and throwing an `Exception` if necessary.

```
public static Fraction newInstance(int numerator, int denomiator) {
    if (denominator == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Denominator cannot be zero.");
    }
    return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
}
```

The other *more glaring* problem lies in your `equals()` method, I will be quite concerned when it actually *modifies* the state of my compared object by calling its `reduceFraction()` method. To better resolve this bug, perhaps you need to ask yourself:

- When I create a new `Fraction` object, can I immediately call `reduceFraction()` to simplify the representation?
- Should `reduceFraction()` really modify the object's state, or should I preserve immutability and return a new `Fraction` object?
- (advanced) If I am preserving immutability, do I also want to compute a hashcode value for my `Fraction` objects so that future comparisons can be done much faster and simpler?

For what it's worth, the method signature to over-ride should really be `equals(Object obj)` (with the necessary check for the correct type), and you are also recommended to over-ride the `hashCode()` method.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof Fraction && <test for values>; // simple example
}
```

Here's more information regarding [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) straight from Javadoc. :)

Answer (score 5):

A few things that I would change (in rough order of importance):

- Rename class to Fraction (as mentioned by Debasis)
- Throw an IllegalArgumentsException in the constructor, instead of calling `print` and `exit(1)`. Users who use your class wrongly will then get a stack trace. This contains context, e.g., where in their code they created the illegal fraction.
- I would prefer to keep the fraction reduced at all times, rather than reducing it when calling `equals`. It will be *very* confusing for people if the object is different before and after an equality comparison.
- The `equals` method is overridden from `Object` (the base class of all java classes). Thus it should have the same signature: `boolean equals(Object other)`. Also, overriding `equals` means you should also override `hashCode` (Otherwise your object will behave strangely when used in data structures).
- Do you really need to consider the case where `b==0` in your GCD implementation?
- Instead of just `readNum` and `readDen`, you could create a `readFraction` function to save yourself some repetition.
- I usually call my constructor arguments the same as the class attributes, and use `this.num = num`. People differ on this, though...

Another remark: You're explicitly asked to create mutator functions. However, the code would be much more robust and simple if a Fraction were immutable. This would mean `final` `num` and `den` attributes (they could even be public). You would only need to check for the zero denominator and reduce the fraction in a single place (the constructor).

If you want to make your fraction really robust, there are a number of other things you should consider:

- should -1/-5 be simplified to 1/5?
- if yes, be careful about -1/`Integer.MIN_VALUE`, because negating `Integer.MIN_VALUE` does not do what one thinks it does.

Comment: +1. We have pretty much the same ideas, but I didn't think of the -1/-5 point. Good catch.

Comment: I updated the comment on equals() taking an Object as a parameter (and requiring an instanceof check). Thanks h.j.k.

Answer (score 3):

General Remark: You have developed a good sense of object oriented approach. Carry on with your good work...

Specific comments:

1. Change the name `FractionClass` to `Fraction`
2. You have defined the `toString()` method for your fraction data type (class). Yet, while printing an object you have simply used:

   ```
   println(numInput + "/" + denInput)
   ```

   You simply need to call the `toString()` method for this.